# What does Datastore quotas mean exactly?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-quotas

I'm a bit confused about what the Datastore quotas mean. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Datastore

Let's take for example the Read quota. If I have 1,000,000 entities of a model, and say I have a task that processes each of those entities by batches of 1000 (either via `fetch` or `fetch_page`), how much of the quota will the task end up using? 1000 or 1,000,000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Batch_operations):

> Performing operations in batches does not affect the cost, regardless
>   of the entity's size. A batch operation for two keys costs two reads,
>   even if one of the keys did not exist.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide the link where I can read the whole thing?

Comment: just google it dude https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Performing+operations+in+batches+does+not+affect+the+cost. Here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/entities#Go_Batch_operations

Comment: I added a link to the Python version.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think the same applies to NDB? I tried searching the docs but couldn't find a similar statement for NDB.

Comment: There is only one Datastore. It does not matter how you access it.